# check if type has certain value types and the keyword value_type itself using c++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-traits

I have following code

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U, typename Tout>
requires std::is_integral< typename T::value_type >
&& std::is_floating_point< typename U::value_type >
&& std::is_floating_point< typename Tout::value_type >
class test
{
    test() =default;
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

I essentially want to ensure that the template argument have certain types, integral or floating point.
There are two issues:

1. The code does not compile. Complains that it needs '(' for function style cast or type construction. Not sure why?
2. I am assuming that T,U,Tout all have the keyword `value_type`. I also want the class to work out if somebody is passing a raw pointer to an integral type or floating point. Is there an easy way to incorporate that?
3. If not, how can we ensure that the error message is very clear when somebody tries to pass a template argument which does not have the `value_type`

Comment: "*I also want the class to work out if somebody is passing a raw pointer to an integral type or floating point.*" That's a completely different question.

Comment: Your second item is not compatible. If `T`, `U`, `Tout` are containers that define `value_type`, you have use `begin()` to get something that can be dereferenced to get a `value_type`. Trying to do that with a pointer will only end in tears. It's simple enough to fix the shown code so that it compiles and produces the correct result, but not for both pointers and containers. That's still possible, but would be somewhat convoluted, and I suspect that you need to reformulate what you're looking for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik are you aware of a reference showing how `value_type` is implemented

Comment: There's nothing particularly complicated about it. Each container defines a member called `value_type`, from its corresponding template parameter. The End.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have several some typos in the code you posted. Cleaned up, the following does what you're looking for:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U, typename Tout>
requires std::is_integral_v<typename T::value_type>
      && std::is_floating_point_v<typename U::value_type>
      && std::is_floating_point_v<typename Tout::value_type>
class test {
public:
    test()=default;
};
```

2. That's a big ask. Maybe someone else can fill in that blank.
3. The error message generated by the compiler (g++ 10.2 here) seems clear enough:

```
int main() {
  test<int, int, int> t;
}
```

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:16:21: error: template constraint failure for 'template<class T, class U, class Tout>  requires (is_integral_v<typename T::value_type>) && (is_floating_point_v<typename U::value_type>) && (is_floating_point_v<typename Tout::value_type>) class test'
   16 |   test<int, int, int> t;
      |                     ^
main.cpp:16:21: note: constraints not satisfied
```