# The syntax of a concept in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

How can we convert the requirements In this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67133581/check-if-type-has-certain-value-types-and-the-keyword-value-type-itself-using-c?noredirect=1#comment118665451_67133581) to a concept

I have attempted the following:

```
template< typename U, typename Tin, typename Tout>
concept MyConditions =
    (
         U::value_type
        &&  Tin::value_type
        &&  Tout::value_type
        && std::is_floating_point_v<typename Tin::value_type>
        && std::is_integral_v<typename U::value_type>
        && std::is_floating_point_v<typename Tout::value_type>
    );
```

This concept is now applied to one of my member functions:

```
class test_concept
{
template< typename U, typename Tin, typename Tout>
requires MyConditions <U, Tin, Tout>
static void test_routine(const U&, const Tin&, Tout& );
}
```

When testing:

```
std::vector<double> test{ };
std::vector<int> testi{ };
std::vector<double> test2{ };

test_concept::test_routine(testi, test, test2);
```

Using `clang` I get the error message that no matching were found, and a note saying:

> note: because substituted constraint expression is ill-formed: missing
> 'typename' prior to
> dependent type name 'vector<int, allocator >::value_type'
> U::value_type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to manually check for the presence of the types. If they're not there, SFINAE will cause your concept to silently return `false` anyway. So:

```
template< typename U, typename Tin, typename Tout>
concept MyConditions =
    std::is_integral_v<typename T::value_type> &&
    std::is_floating_point_v<typename U::value_type> &&
    std::is_floating_point_v<typename Tout::value_type>;
```

But if you want to explicitly check for the types, here's the syntax:

```
template< typename U, typename Tin, typename Tout>
concept MyConditions =
    requires
    {
        typename U::value_type;
        typename Tin::value_type;
        typename Tout::value_type;
    } &&
    std::is_integral_v<typename T::value_type> &&
    std::is_floating_point_v<typename U::value_type> &&
    std::is_floating_point_v<typename Tout::value_type>;
```

You can also move all conditions into the `requires`:

```
template< typename U, typename Tin, typename Tout>
concept MyConditions =
    requires
    {
        typename U::value_type;
        typename Tin::value_type;
        typename Tout::value_type;
        requires std::is_integral_v<typename T::value_type>;
        requires std::is_floating_point_v<typename U::value_type>;
        requires std::is_floating_point_v<typename Tout::value_type>;
    };
```

Also you should prefer the standard concepts to the old traits:

```
template< typename U, typename Tin, typename Tout>
concept MyConditions =
    requires
    {
        typename U::value_type;
        typename Tin::value_type;
        typename Tout::value_type;
        requires std::integral<typename T::value_type>;
        requires std::floating_point<typename U::value_type>;
        requires std::floating_point<typename Tout::value_type>;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the different options!. What do you mean by prefer standard concepts? 
Should we prefer `std::integral<typename T::value_type>` over  `std::integral_v<typename T::value_type>`? If yes, then why?

Comment: @A2LBK Yes, that's what I meant. I don't think it makes a difference here, but in some cases it does. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062386/does-constraint-subsumption-only-apply-to-concepts

Comment: While you could move all conditions into the `requires`, it's not a good idea to do this blindly because it turns your concept from a recognized conjunction of atomic constraints into a one big blob. Taking the concept from the question, this means that `MyConditions` is no longer more specific than any of its `std::integral/floating_point` pieces, so you can no longer overload a `MyConditions<T, ...>` function with a `std::integral<typename T::value_type>` function and have the overload resolution work as you'd expect.